# How can getdate["weekday"] start from Monday instead of sunday?

Tags: php

I need to start the "weekday" of `getdate()` to Monday instead of Sunday, is there a way to do this?

Here is my code, don't worry about the parameters in `validatePlanningVendeur` the problem is when i try to get the current date `arret`, so that it can validate from Monday till `arret`.

You might notice i wrote `$arret = $today["wday"]-1;`,this is my attempt to bypass the `wkday` Sunday = 0 so that Monday is 0, but now it does not work for Sunday because it is equal to -1.

To get it short, right now `$arret` work from Monday to Saturday only.

```
function validatePlanningVendeur($week, $vendeur, $boutique, $type_connecte, $user_connecte){
        $connexion = connexion();
        // Getting the current date in order to get the end
        $today = getdate();
        $arret = $today["wday"]-1; // attempt to bypass sunday = 0
        echo($arret);
        // echo("Aujourdhui : " . $today["wday"]);
        // echo("arret: " . $arret);

        // We get every day of the week until today ($arret)
        for($i = 0; $i <= $arret ; $i++){
            // On crée le year-month-day pour chaque jour de la semaine
            // echo($week[$i]);
            $dateCurrent = getdate($week[$i]);
            $day = $dateCurrent['mday'];
            $month = $dateCurrent['mon'];
            $year = $dateCurrent['year'];

            // Used to fetch from DB
            $jour = $year. '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
            // echo("Jour : " . $jour . " ");

            if($type_connecte == 1){ //Si c'est un RPV qui est connecté
                // On assigne id_validation = 1
                $request_validate = $connexion->prepare("UPDATE plannings SET id_validation = ? WHERE date_planning = ? AND id_employe = ? AND id_validation = ? AND id_boutique = ?");
                $request_validate->execute(array(1, $jour, $vendeur, 0, $boutique));
            }else{// On ne prend pas en compte la valeur boutique pour le RC
                $request_validate = $connexion->prepare("UPDATE plannings SET id_validation = ? WHERE date_planning = ? AND id_employe = ? AND id_validation = ?");
                $request_validate->execute(array(1, $jour, $vendeur, 0,));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us a little more about the intended calculation first.

Comment: You can't change a function signature that doesn't supply options to do so. Listen to Ro's advice and describe what you want your code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```php
$today = new DateTime();
// Get ordinal number of the day of the week by ISO 8601.
// It starts from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday).
$arret = $today->format('N'); // Today is 7th day
for ($i = 0; $i <= $arret - 1 ; $i++) {
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function myweekday($d) 
{
    $r = (getdate($d)['wday']==0 ? 7 : getdate($d)['wday']-1 );
    return $r;
}

for ($i=0; $i<=7; $i++) {
    $t = time() + $i*24*3600;
    echo getdate($t)['weekday'], " ", myweekday($t). "\n";
}
```

output:

```
Sunday 7
Monday 0
Tuesday 1
Wednesday 2
Thursday 3
Friday 4
Saturday 5
Sunday 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
$week_days[saturday]=getdate();
$week_days[sunday]=getdate();
$week_days[monday]=getdate();
$week_days[tuesday]=getdate();
$week_days[wednesday]=getdate();
$week_days[thursday]=getdate();
$week_days[friday]=getdate();

$day_order[1]=$week_days[monday];
$day_order[2]=$week_days[tuesday];
$day_order[3]=$week_days[wednesday];
$day_order[4]=$week_days[thursday];
$day_order[5]=$week_days[friday];
$day_order[6]=$week_days[saturday];
$day_order[4]=$week_days[sunday];
```